# How does "$F_Z(z) = \iint_{D_z}f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$" read in plain English?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

See: [this book](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf). Page-123.

How does the following integral notation read in plain English?

> $$F_Z(z) = \iint_{D_z}f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$
>   [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjCb0.png)

As far as I can tell,

> The value of $F_Z(z)$ is equal to the value of integration of the function $f(x, y)$ over the **rectangular** region $Dz$, where $Dz$ is the region bounded by $(X, Y)$

1. Am I correct?
2. **Is the region $(X, Y)$ rectangular?**

Comment: I certainly see no reason to assume the region is rectangular. Also it makes no sense to have a region bounded by a pair of random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the language down to your special case, on line 4.10 the text defines $D_z$ as the set of points $(x,y)$ with $f_{XY} (x,y) \leq z$, $f_{XY}$ being the joint density.  This need not be rectangular at all.

The way it is written in that section is, admittedly, very confusing.

Comment: Is the region bounded by $(x, y)$ or $(X,Y)$? Why?

Comment: One is a pair of points, one is a pair of random variables.